# Mysqli Wild Card Insert with data range

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a very large data (not a file) to insert into a students' database. It will be very difficult to type every inch of it, loop and insert. However, it follows a specific pattern and it's in a range of specific numbers.

Below is an example of what I am talking about.

**Student's Reference Numbers**

Sample range: **APS00001 - APS02000**

The first three characters are constant. but the rest are not. The data has to be inserted based on the given range.

```
<?php mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO table (reference) VALUES('each of the data in the sample range')"); ?>
```

So I could generate the sequence using this code

```
<?php
$array_items = array();

for ($i=0; $i <= 2000; $i++) { 
  $array_items[] .= $i;
}
print_r($array_items); // prints the sequence
?>
```

Comment: Does the file already exist? If so you can bulk-load it into MySQL, especially if it's in (or can be saved into) a delimited format such as CSV. Investigate the LOAD DATA command.

Comment: The file doesn't exist, would have been much easier to do that if a file was available. It's just a bunch of reference numbers which isn't stored in any digital file format.

Comment: So you want something which would auto-generate the number sequence and then insert it into the database, is that right? Are there other fields to go with each number, or you just want to insert these reference numbers alone? It's a bit unclear. Give us a proper sample of a few rows of the data (you can anonymise names, the important thing is the structure and type of data).

Comment: @ADyson yh sure right. I want something that auto-generates the number sequence. No other fields will go with each of the numbers. Users will manually update other fields when logged in.

Comment: Ok so I would start by writing some code which generates numbers between 1 and 2000 and puts them in an array. Can you try that? (it could be done with a simple `for` loop).

Comment: @ADyson yes sure. I will try.

Comment: Use the "edit" button to update your question with your code, once you've got it.

Comment: Is it just one field being inserted?

Comment: Yes please. One field. I can generate the sequence now

Comment: Your PHP version won't pad the numbers like you've shown as a desired result. See my answer for a SQL version that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an SQL solution to your `INSERT` problem.

Run this to loop from 1 to 2000. It generates APS0001, padding the number as it goes.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_data $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data ()

BEGIN

DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 1;

WHILE count <= 2000 DO
    INSERT INTO `tbl1`(`col3`) VALUES(CONCAT("APS",LPAD(count, 4, '0')));
    SET count = count + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL insert_data();
```

Since the original post was updated, here is a PHP solution:

```
<?php
// add $conn info

for ($i = 1; $i <= 2000; $i++) {
    $insdata = "APS" . str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO table (reference) VALUES('$insdata')");
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP solution added.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statement with parameter binding. To pad the string to a given length use [`str_pad()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). You can prepend the `APS` string either in PHP or in SQL using `CONCAT()`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (reference) VALUES(CONCAT('APS', ?))";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value_to_be_inserted);

$array_items = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $array_items[] .= +$i;

    $value_to_be_inserted = str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Don't prepare in the loop. Only execute inside the loop.

Comment: @WanPeninsula I assume you didn't downvote. I removed your edit, because questions should only be questions and your solution in there made it confusing. If you want you can add your solution as yet another answer.